# How to connect three chains together in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

How to connect three chains? I want to draw the following diagram using tikz:

[image: The diagram I want to draw].

Unfortunately, in my system, compilation of the following code doesn't finish. How to draw the above diagram using chains? Either branch or three independent chains that are connected.
Consider the following MWE:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{listofitems}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,chains,decorations.markings}


 \tikzset{% 
   attach arrow/.style={
   decoration={
    markings,
     mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc 
    arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
     \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
    mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
    mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
    mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
    mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc 
  arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
     coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
    },
 postaction=decorate,
 },
 attach arrow/.default=0.5,
 arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
 }

 \begin{document}
 \readlist*\myarray{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P,Q}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>={Stealth[bend]},
   block/.style={draw, rectangle,minimum height=1.6em,minimum width=9em,
   rotate=90,},decide/.code={\ifnum#1<7
    \tikzset{execute at begin node={ }}
   \else
   \tikzset{execute at begin node={}}
   \fi}]
   \begin{scope}[start chain=A placed {at={(\tikzchaincount*3em,0)}},
   nodes={on chain,block,join= by {thick,->},decide=\tikzchaincount}]
    \path foreach \X in {1,...,17}{node[fill=gray](A\X){\myarray[\X]}};
   \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[start chain=B placed {at={(\tikzchaincount*3em,4)}},
   nodes={on chain,block,join= by {thick,->},decide=\tikzchaincount}]
   \path foreach \X in {1,...,17}{node[fill=gray]{\myarray[\X]}};
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[start chain=C placed {at={(\tikzchaincount*3em+15,2)}},
     nodes={on chain,circle,decide=\tikzchaincount}]
    \path foreach \X in {1,...,16}{node[fill=gray](CS\X){CS}};
    \path foreach \X in {1,...,16}{ \draw[thin, ->] (A\X)-- (CS\X};
 \end{scope}


 \path (A-1.north) -- ++ (-1em,2) node[anchor=south,rotate=90](pool){}
    -- ++ (-0.5em,0) node[block,anchor=south,fill=gray](A-0)
      { Input 310};

   \draw[thick, ->] (A-0) -- (B-1);
   \draw[thick, ->] (A-0) -- (A-1);

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

I want to connect from the first chain to the circle chain in middle and from the circle chain to the next element in the first chain. Likewise from the third chain to the circle chain in the middle.

EDIT: Previously, the above code was completely compiled on my system. Now, its compilation doesn't finish no matter how long it takes.

Comment: You code contains errors, e.g. `(A) -- (O};` (error near the closing brace). Moreover, having `\draw` commands inside a `\path` probably doesn't work either: `\path foreach ... {\draw ... }`

Comment: @gernot, I have compiled it in my system, and it worked. I don't know what is the problem. How should one resolve this error? I don't know about \path, how correct it?

Comment: Sorry, your code contain errors. Also is missing `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko, \end{document} is there.

Comment: @Zarko,  please see the question now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @gernot, please see the question now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is not clear to me, what is your problem:

  - reproduce showed image with some (simple) code or
  - fixed your code (in which I must admit that I was lost)
- Showed image I can reproduce with the following (quite simple) MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending,
                chains,
                positioning
                }

\tikzset{%
 node distance = 22mm and 22mm,
   start chain = A going right,
   start chain = B going right,
   start chain = C going right,
    arr/.style = {-Stealth},
   boxA/.style = {draw, minimum size=11mm, font=\sffamily,
                  on chain=A, join=by arr},
   boxB/.style = {draw, minimum size=11mm, font=\sffamily,
                  on chain=B, join=by arr},
      C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=11mm,
                  on chain=C},
every edge/.append style={draw, -{Stealth[bend]}, bend angle=30}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}    
    \node   [boxA]  {A\i};

    \node   [boxB, below=of A-1]  {B1};
\foreach \i in {2, 3}
    \node   [boxB]  {B\i};
\path (A-1) -- node [C] {C1} (B-2);
\node               [C] {C2};
%%%%
\scoped[bend left]
\path   (A-1) edge (C-1) (C-1) edge (A-2)   
        (A-2) edge (C-2) (C-2) edge (A-3); 
\scoped[bend right]
\path   
(B-1) edge (C-1) (C-1) edge (B-2)
        (B-2) edge (C-2) (C-2) edge (B-3);
           \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
in cases of longer chains of nodes and nodes are rectangle instead square shapes, than the following code will be better:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending,
                chains,
                positioning
                }

\tikzset{%
 node distance = 22mm and 32mm, on grid, % <---
   start chain = A going right,
   start chain = B going right,
   start chain = C going right,
    arr/.style = {-Stealth},
   base/.style = {draw, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=12mm, % <---
                  font=\sffamily},
   boxA/.style = {base, on chain=A, join=by arr},
   boxB/.style = {base, on chain=B, join=by arr},
      C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=8mm,
                  on chain=C},
every edge/.append style={draw, -{Stealth[bend]}}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\def\NumA{5}                % number of nodes in chains A and B
\def\NumB{\numexpr\NumA-1}  % number of nodes in chain C

\foreach \i in {1, ...,\NumA}    
    \node   [boxA]  {A\i};

    \node   [boxB, below=of A-1]  {B1};
\foreach \i in {2, ...,\NumA}
    \node   [boxB]  {B\i};
\path (A-1) -- node [C] {C1} (B-2);
\foreach \i in {2, ...,\NumB}
\node               [C] {C\i};
%%%%
\scoped[bend left=25]
{\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,\NumB}
\path   (A-\i) edge (C-\i) (C-\i) edge[bend left] (A-\j);
} 
\scoped[bend right=25]
{\foreach \i [count=\j from 2]  in {1,...,\NumB}
\path   (B-\i) edge (C-\i)    (C-\i) edge (B-\j);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want this image.

Comment: How to change the spacing between nodes and change squares to rectangles?

Comment: @user85361, **(i)** distances between nodes are determined by `node distance=<vertical distance> and <horizontal distance>`, **(ii)** for rectangles: replace `minimum size=<size>` with `\minimum width=<size of lenght>, minimum height=<size of height>`.

Comment: @user85361, however, replace squares by rectangles influence on bended arrows. It may happen, that you will need manually tweak their starts at rectangles.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @user85361, see addendum to answer. I spirit of site policy you can your thankfulness express by upvoting of answer ;-)