# How to draw three chains in relation to each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I want to draw the following:
[image]

This question is related but I can't infer from its answer [How to draw to independent chains?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633690/how-to-connect-three-chains-together-in-tikz/633800?noredirect=1#comment1580414_633800)

Comment: What you try so far? BTW, this picture seems to be easier to draw without use of chains, for example in two loops.

Comment: @Zarko, I don't know how to do it? I can draw a chain but I don't know how to draw it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should make yourself more familiar with `tikz` package
- for start read "2 Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students" and than "Part III Ti*k*Z ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm" from package documentation (TZi*k*Z and PGF Manual for Version 3.1.9a)
- there on site exist huge number of answers with `tikzpicture` examples with code and images
- it is worth to look in the [example.net](https://texample.net/) site

Your image is very elementary, so for start examine the following solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{%
 node distance = 8mm, 
    box/.style = {draw, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=2mm, 
                  inner sep=0mm, node contents={}},
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,2, 4,5,6,7,8, 12, 17}
{
\node (a\i) at (0.5*\i,0.4) [box, anchor=south];
\node (b\i)                 [box, below=of a\i];
}
\foreach \i in {0, 3, 9,10,11, 13,14,15,16}
\node (c\i) at (0.5*\i,0.0) [box];
%
\draw   (c0)  -- (a1)  -- (a2)  -- 
        (c3)  -- (a4)  -- (a5)  -- (a6)  -- (a7) -- (a8) --
        (c9)  -- (c10) -- (c11) -- (a12) --
        (c13) -- (c14) -- (c15) -- (c16) -- (a17)
%               
        (c0)  -- (b1)  -- (b2)  --
        (c3)  -- (b4)  -- (b5)  -- (b6)  -- (b7) -- (b8) --
        (c9)  -- (c10) -- (c11) -- (b12) --
        (c13) -- (c14) -- (c15) -- (c16) -- (b17);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your excellent suggestions.